# how to solve my Problem i use laravel vesion 5.8 and i want to see route:list on command line but i gut always ERROR

Tags: laravel

the ERRO IN my visual STUDIO Code  terminal is :
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Controllername] does not exist.

at C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_projects\massar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:809
    805| 
    806|         try {
    807|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    808|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {

> 809|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
>       810|         }
>       811| 
>       812|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
>       813|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

2   C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_projects\massar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:807 
      ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\Controllername does not exist")
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel_projects\massar>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, does it? The error says it can't find the `Controllername` controller, which, according to the namespace *should* be located in the `app/http/Controllers/` folder. Is there such a controller?

If the controller doesn't exist and you're using it in your routes, the command will keep throwing errors.

2 Options:

1. `php artisan make:controller Controllername` to create the controller if it doesn't exist.
2. Remove or comment out every route that uses `Controllername`.